# What challenge can I face staying in Talesh mountains in Iran?

Tags: iran, mountains

I saw some videos of the [Talesh mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talesh_County) in Iran e.g. :

- [Spring at Talesh Mountains](https://youtu.be/c4jX4lLmVCA)

I am curious about access to the healthcare facility (I have asthma), electricity, and the Internet. Can anyone give me any information about these?

Secondly, how welcoming are people there to foreigners?

Comment: Whats *your* nationality?  Being arrested for spying should be high up on your list of “other issues with this idea” if you are from certain countries…

Comment: Are you _sure_ travelling to Iran is a good idea, in general? https://imgur.com/a/tT78aIi

Comment: "how welcoming are people there to foreigners?" it's going to massively depend on *which* kind of foreigner you are...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an equipped hospital in Talesh city. Talesh peaks are usually less than 3,000 meters high and have a very clean climate. There is generally electricity at high altitudes but no internet.

Regarding your second question. In the villages, the guest is very dear to the people. You are having a great time among the villagers.

Comment: Not having Internet would be a major issue for me. Coz, I can't work without the Internet.

Comment: There is an Internet in the city. But not at high altitudes. Internet is disconnected in about 1 hour from the city.
If you want to be in the village and have internet, I suggest Masouleh.
Masouleh is a historical village in Gilan province. You can find a lot of information about Masouleh on the internet

Comment: I have heard that Iranian people are very welcoming and lovable. The only think that I heard not very good is about complicated trafic rule on the road.

Comment: Driving in the capital is a bit difficult due to the large population. In other places, it's not as intense as you said

Comment: @MostafaNZ, *Masouleh is a historical village in Gilan province.* --- I don't like historical villages. I am looking for a naturally beautiful village, preferably in the mountains.

Comment: Masuleh is a historical village in the heart of nature. See the photos of Masuleh on Google. There are many peaks for climbing around Masuleh. Masuleh is located in Gilan province. The province of Gilan has a very beautiful nature. One of which is Talash and Masuleh.
The north of Iran has many areas suitable for people interested in green nature. Like the forest, the sea, and the mountains